# Show/hide div for search results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a results div below my search box which I would like to hide when the search isn't being used. If I remove my padding and border from the div, then it's hidden because it's empty, but ideally I would like to keep the styling. If I hide the div with `style="display: none;"` then when the results are displayed the div is still hidden, so I'm assuming I need to change the javascript to "unhide" the div? Unfortunately I wouldn't know where to do this in the script.

```
HTML:
<div class="col div-parent">
    <input type="text" class="form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="search-box" id="search-box" autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Search ...">
    <div class="result div-child bg-gray-200 pt-3 px-3 text-sm border border-secondary rounded-3"></div>
</div>
```

```
Javascript:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#search-box').on("keyup input", function(){
                /* Get input value on change */
                var inputVal = $(this).val();
                var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
                if(inputVal.length) {
                    $.get("ajax-live-search.php?rID=<?php echo $region; ?>&oID=2", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                        // Display the returned data in browser
                        resultDropdown.html(data);
                    });
                } else {
                    resultDropdown.empty();
                }
            });
            // Set search input value on click of result item
            $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
                $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
                $(this).parent(".result").empty();
            });
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what you are looking for

```js
var underSearchbar = document.getElementById("underSearchbar");
    /*hide at the beginning*/
    underSearchbar.style.display = "none";
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#search-box').on("keyup input", function () {
        /* show div on input */
        underSearchbar.style.display = "block";
        /* Get input value on change */
        var inputVal = $(this).val();
        var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
        if (inputVal.length) {
          $.get("ajax-live-search.php?rID=<?php echo $region; ?>&oID=2", { term: inputVal }).done(function (data) {
            // Display the returned data in browser
            resultDropdown.html(data);
          });
        } else {
          resultDropdown.empty();
          /* hide again if empty */
          underSearchbar.style.display = "none";
        }
      });
      // Set search input value on click of result item
      $(document).on("click", ".result p", function () {
        $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
        $(this).parent(".result").empty();
      });
    });
```

```html
  <div class="col div-parent">
    <input type="text" class="form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="search-box" id="search-box"
      autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search ...">
    <div class="result div-child bg-gray-200 pt-3 px-3 text-sm border border-secondary rounded-3" id="underSearchbar"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Glad to help, if you really want to make it look cool you can use "Opacity" and "Transition" so it have a nice animation

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the cleanest way, but cant you just use use the fadeOut() function when there is no input on the result element and fadeIn() when there is an input val.. That should do what you want, no?

[Here](https://api.jquery.com/fadein/) is the documentation.

Something like this will hide it by default(since no input) and show it when there is.
I hope this helps

```
if(inputVal.length) {
                $.get("ajax-live-search.php?rID=<?php echo $region; ?>&oID=2", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                    // Display the returned data in browser
                    resultDropdown.html(data);
                    $("#yourelement").fadeIn();
                });
            } else {
                resultDropdown.empty();
                $("#yourelement").fadeOut();
            }
```

Comment: This sort of works. If I add it like you have it here, the div isn't hidden when the pages loads. It only hides it when I delete any text in the search bar. If I place the fadeOut line directly after the document.ready line, the you can see it fade out when the page loads. Thanks for your suggestion though - I've learnt some more about JS

Comment: This means your if clause has a wrong condition somewhere. meaning inputVal does not default to nothing.. but has something, Check the if statements you are using to make sure it returns false(since the fade out is on the else statement) or just set the default state of your search bar to hidden(with css) since it will auto pop up when there is a value per the if clause(Hannon proposed this)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you should use `visibility: hidden;` instead of `display: None`, and if you want the result placeholder (`.result`) to stay showing, then don't throw the result data into it directly but put it in a second div inside it, that you can display and remove whenever you like based on your criteria, if you could tell us your criteria of showing and hiding the result, I may be able to supply you with code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure but this might help

```
<div class="col div-parent">
    <input type="text" class="form-control-sm border border-secondary" name="search-box" id="search-box" autocomplete="off"
            placeholder="Search ...">
    <div class="result div-child bg-gray-200 pt-3 px-3 text-sm border border-secondary rounded-3"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#search-box').on("keyup input", function(){
                /* Get input value on change */
                var inputVal = $(this).val();
                var resultDropdown = $(this).siblings(".result");
                if(inputVal.length) {
                    $.get("ajax-live-search.php?rID=<?php echo $region; ?>&oID=2", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
                        // Display the returned data in browser
                        resultDropdown.html(data);
                    });
                } else {
                    resultDropdown.empty();
                }
                $('.result').css("display","block")
                    })
                $('#search-box').focusout( function() {
                $('.result').css("display","none")
                            });
            // Set search input value on click of result item
            $(document).on("click", ".result p", function(){
                $(this).parents(".search-box").find('input[type="text"]').val($(this).text());
                $(this).parent(".result").empty();
            });
        });
 </script>
```

Styles

```
<style>
    .result {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
```